Create line chart of baby weight but have bug
I made a line chart to show the pr3, pr25, pr50, pr75, pr97 line of baby weight, but the lines have some bugs.
Here is the chart I want:

and this is what i get:

make a struct for the data
struct WeightData: Identifiable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var age: Int // age
    var weight: Double // weight
}

the data of each pr value(each line have 24 datas):
var linePr3: [WeightData] = [
        WeightData(age: 0, weight: 2.5),
        WeightData(age: 1, weight: 3.4),
        ...
    ]
var linePr25: [WeightData] = [
...
]
...

After using the above code the chart get something wrong.
Chart {
    // 3rd percentile line
    ForEach(linePr3, id: \.id) { index in
        LineMark(
            x: .value("Age", index.age),
            y: .value("Weight", index.weight)
        )
        .foregroundStyle(Color.red)
    }
}

Can anyone provide some suggestions on how to solve this kind of error.
